# How to convert 2D numpy array to One Hot Encoding?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, numpy-ndarray, one-hot-encoding

I was trying to apply one hot encoding for the following data. But I am confused about the output. Before applying one hot encoding the shape of data is (5,10) and after applying one hot encoding the shape of data is (5,20). But each letter would be encoded as a 4 element. So, after applying one hot encoding, the shape should be (5, 40) instead of (5,10). How can I solve this?

```
X = [[‘A’, ‘G’, ‘T’, ‘G’, ‘T’, ‘C’, ‘T’, ‘A’, ‘A’, ‘C’],
     [‘A’, ‘G’, ‘T’, ‘G’, ‘T’, ‘C’, ‘T’, ‘A’, ‘A’, ‘C’],
     [‘G’, ‘C’, ‘C’, ‘A’, ‘C’, ‘T’, ‘C’, ‘G’, ‘G’, ‘T’],
     [‘G’, ‘C’, ‘C’, ‘A’, ‘C’, ‘T’, ‘C’, ‘G’, ‘G’, ‘T’],
     [‘G’, ‘C’, ‘C’, ‘A’, ‘C’, ‘T’, ‘C’, ‘G’, ‘G’, ‘T’]]
Y = np.array(X)
print('Shape of numpy array', Y.shape)

# one hot encoding

onehot_encoder = OneHotEncoder(sparse=False)
onehot_encoded = onehot_encoder.fit_transform(Y)
print(onehot_encoded)
print('Shape of one hot encoding', onehot_encoded.shape)


Output:

Shape of numpy array (5, 10)
[[1. 0. 0. 1. 0. 1. 0. 1. 0. 1. 1. 0. 0. 1. 1. 0. 1. 0. 1. 0.]
 [1. 0. 0. 1. 0. 1. 0. 1. 0. 1. 1. 0. 0. 1. 1. 0. 1. 0. 1. 0.]
 [0. 1. 1. 0. 1. 0. 1. 0. 1. 0. 0. 1. 1. 0. 0. 1. 0. 1. 0. 1.]
 [0. 1. 1. 0. 1. 0. 1. 0. 1. 0. 0. 1. 1. 0. 0. 1. 0. 1. 0. 1.]
 [0. 1. 1. 0. 1. 0. 1. 0. 1. 0. 0. 1. 1. 0. 0. 1. 0. 1. 0. 1.]]
 Shape of one hot encoding (5, 20)
```

Comment: I'm not sure the output should be (5,40). You have 5 examples, each consisting of 10 letters. If each letter becomes a list of 4 values, then you will have 5 examples of 10 4-valued lists. That would be a (5, 10, 4) array (i.e., three-dimensional)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to one-hot encode each column separately so you will get 4 new columns for each column in your ndarray:

```
X = np.array(X)

# Get unique classes.
classes = np.unique(X)

# Replace classes with itegers.
X = np.searchsorted(classes, X)

# Get an identity matrix.
eye = np.eye(classes.shape[0])

# Iterate over all columns
# and get one-hot encoding for each column.
X = np.concatenate([eye[i] for i in X.T], axis=1)

X.shape
# (5, 40)
```

Consider the following example:

```
[['A', 'G'],
 ['C', 'C'],
 ['T', 'A']]
```

You will get 8 (2 x 4) columns in your one-hot encoded ndarray:

```
  Column 0      Column 1         
 A  C  G  T    A  C  G  T

 1  0  0  0    0  0  1  0
 0  1  0  0    0  1  0  0
 0  0  0  1    1  0  0  0
```

Comment: Thank you. It works. But I have a bit confusion. Could you please explain me why the value of G and T is similar in the output? 
If I consider A=[1. 0. 0. 0.], G=[0. 1. 0. 0.], C=[0. 0. 1. 0.], T=[0. 0. 0. 1.]
The output should be [1. 0. 0. 0. 0. 1. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 1. 0. 1. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 1. 0. 0. 1. 0. 0. 0. 0. 1. 1. 0. 0. 0. 1. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 1. 0.]  for ['A' 'G' 'T' 'G' 'T' 'C' 'T' 'A' 'A' 'C']
But it shows:
[1. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 1. 0. 0. 0. 1. 0. 0. 0. 1. 0. 0. 0. 1. 0. 1. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 1. 1. 0. 0. 0. 1. 0. 0. 0. 0. 1. 0. 0.]

Comment: @TanzilaIslamMohita I added one example. You can accept my answer if you like it.

Comment: Now, I understood. Thank you.

Comment: If the sequence is like [['A', 'G'], ['C', 'N'], ['T', 'A']], 'N' is a missing value. Is it possible to replace 'N' by 0 0 0 0 by using this approach? The output will look like the following for ['C', 'N'] => [0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0]